# Bringing up the carousel of open windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

Windows has the familiar <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key combination to switch between recently used windows. I've also seen it set up so that the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key can be used to bring up a carousel of all open windows that can be cycled between without holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

I don't know how make it do that, and wouldn't want to do exactly that in any case because I need the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for use as <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I would love to be able to bring up the carousel of open windows by some other method (e.g. I could sacrifice caps lock for that purpose cheerfully enough). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. On non-US keyboards that have the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, you can use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> which does the same. If you only have a right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, you will have to use it in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>**LAlt**</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>**RAlt**</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are the same on US keyboards.

Comment: When you have AltGr, there is no need to additionally press Ctrl. AltGr+Tab invokes the functionality the OP asked for.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I've corrected the answer.